# Velocity of bead when a light inextensible frictionless cord becomes taut. (Pathfinder methods of impulse build up 3rd question)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

The complete question is

> "A thin light inextensible frictionless chord of length $l$ wearing a small bead is tied between two nails that are in the same level a distance $(0.5)l$ apart. Initially the bead is held close to a nail and released. Find speed of the bead immediately after the chord becomes taut."

The Answer given is $\sqrt{\frac{3gl}{20}}$.

I tried to find $h$ by applying conditions for $F_x=0$ and pythagoras relation of $x\ y$ and $h$($x$ = part of rope on the side from which bead was released, $y$ = horizontal distance from the initial nail and $h$ = height it descended)

Comment: I wouldn't trust a physics book whose author doesn't know what the word "chord" means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the velocity to be perpendicular to net tension at the bottom point.Use pythagoras to find the angles.Try to solve Further

Answer (score 0):

If the mass of the cord is ignored, then the bead will drop straight down (a distance h) until the cord is taunt. Then $h^2 + (0.5L)^2 = (L – h)^2$. I do not agree with the given answer.

Comment: Yes I thought that too and did that too but I saw the answer was wrong so I thought my method was wrong. Its just that answer key of pathfinder though not entirely flawless but it is usually correct and we wrong. so I assumed it moved horizontally as well but that's where i got stuck. Thanks for your answer

Comment: The bead cannot  move horizontally until after the cord is taunt.

Comment: I know right but the answer made me confused